# How to polymorphism in c# (normaly and with Abstract)

Tags: c#, polymorphism, abstract

I understand how to polymorphism functions in classes and to override.
What i dont understand is how to use it for Objects.

```
abstract class Film
{
    protected string film_name;

    public Film(string film_name)
    {
        this.film_name = film_name;
    }

    public string GetFilmName()
    {
        return this.film_name;
    }



}

class Siries : Film
{
    private int season_number;

    public Siries
    {
        // What do i need to write here? and why?..
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to read some guides on C# polymorphism: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx

Comment: Polymorphism is more about overiding methods and properties than constructors... What do you mean by 'how to use it for Objects?" Classes are templates of objects, so if you understand that for classes, there is nothing more to understand in 'objects'.

Comment: Downvoting because one could grab a book, google it, do some research before letting others solve their problems.

Answer (score 0):

If Siries is a specific Film.

The keyword "base" calls the constructor of the baseclass "Film".

```
public Siries() : base("siries")
{
}
```

If you want to make series with a name and a number you have to make it like this.

```
public Siries(string siries_name, int season_number) : base(siries_name)
{
    this.season_number = season_number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it can be answer of what you expecting.

Just create an object of base class that is pointing to derived class. Which is a concept of inheritance.

According to your example,

```
Film f = new Siries();
f.method()// Method what you expect to call by object
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *redesigning* with *properties* instead of `Get` functions; as for your question in the derived class constructor you should implement

- call an appropriate *base class constructor*
- add *derived class* logic

something like this:

```
  abstract class Film {
    // let field be private, but property be protected 
    private string m_FilmName;

    public Film(string filmName) {
      FilmName = filmName;
    }

    // FilmNam is more natural/readable in your case than GetFilmName() method
    public string FilmName {
      get {
        return m_FilmName;
      }
      protected set { // "private set" seems to be a better choice
        // do not forget to validate the input value in public/protected methods
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
          throw new ArgumentNullException("value", 
            "FileName must not be null or white space");

        m_FilmName = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

...

```
  class Siries: Film {
    private int m_SeasonNumber;

    // Answer: 
    //   1. You have to call base class constructor ": base(filmName)"
    //   2. Add up some logic with "seasonNumber" - "SeasonNumber = seasonNumber;"
    public Siries(String filmName, int seasonNumber = 1)
      : base(filmName) {

      SeasonNumber = seasonNumber;
    }

    public int SeasonNumber {
      get {
        return m_SeasonNumber;
      } 
      protected set { // may be "private set" or just "set" (public)
        // do not forget to validate the input value in public/protected methods
        if (value <= 0)
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRange("value", "SeasonNumber must be positive");

        m_SeasonNumber = value;
      }
    }
  }
```